# PSD.js in react error fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, psd

I have a reactjs project using **[psd.js](https://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/)** and on my dropzone config like this

```
accept: function(file, done){
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = handleReaderLoad;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        function handleReaderLoad(evt) {
          console.log(evt.target.result);
          let psdFile = PSD.fromFile(evt.target.result);
          psdFile.parse();
          console.log(psdFile);
        }
        done();
      },
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
    at Function.fromFile (init.coffee:6)
    at FileReader.handleReaderLoad (index.js?03a7:153)
```

in my webpack config i inlclude :

```
node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
```

Because if I don't include it, the error is: `not found fs module`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PSD.fromEvent(evt)`, not `PSD.fromFile`.

The former reads the blob from a file input, while the latter tries to hit the filesystem which is obviously absent in the browser context.

So I guess your code should look like this (but I'm not quite sure)

```
accept: function(file, done){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = handleReaderLoad;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    function handleReaderLoad(evt) {
      PSD.fromEvent(evt).then(function (psd) {
           // here you can access the parsed file as psd
           console.log(psd.tree().export());
          done();
      });
    }

  },
```

Comment: if i used `PSD.fromEvent()` the errror is `Uncaught TypeError: PSD.fromEvent is not a function
    at FileReader.handleReaderLoad`. whats wrong @pawel